# Error when hitting Run in Eclipse 2D

Tags: java, eclipse, slick2d

I am a noob learning basic game programming in Slick 2D Using Eclipse and java
I am following a tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_871076&feature=iv&src_vid=NoksHLldlcM&v=oWm5JY6IlUo and when i hit run it does not work. I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found:     testdata/alphamap.png
at org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(ResourceLoader.java:69)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:169)
at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:196)
at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:170)
at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:158)
at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:136)
at org.newdawn.slick.tests.AlphaMapTest.init(AlphaMapTest.java:33)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:390)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:314)
at org.newdawn.slick.tests.AlphaMapTest.main(AlphaMapTest.java:79)
```

This is what I am attempting

```
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;


public class Main extends BasicGame{

private static final String Slick2D = null;

public Main(String title) {
    super(title);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

//this is where execution starts
public static void man(String args[]) throws SlickException {

    AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new Main("First Slick2D"));
    app.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
    app.start();

}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    // draw all the graphics
    g.fillOval(200, 200, 100, 300)
    g.fillRect(300, 200, 100, 200)
    g.fillRoundRect(500, 200, 100, 50, 30)
    g.drawLine(0, 0, 800, 600)
    g.drawString(Welcome to Slick2D, 400, 0)
}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {
    // load all fonts, graphics, sounds, etc.

}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer arg0, int arg1) throws SlickException {
    // game logic (AI, user input)

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's simply can't find image. check your scr folder for testdata folder and check if it contains alphamap.png (or you can delete some code where you getting and setting  this picture)

Answer (score 0):

Slick expects images to be in a folder called images. I'm not sure why, but it does.

Your direcetories should look like this:

\src\Main.java

\images\alphamap.png

If that doesn't work, make sure your directories are properly named and *are within the project folder*, not the src folder.

Example:

\MyProject\src\Main.java is your source code

\MyProject\images\alphamap.png